# Aggregate Dataframe by multiple indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| index | period | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20181231 | 1 |
| 2 | 20181231 | 2 |
| 3 | 20181231 | 3 |
| 4 | 20190131 | 1 |
| 5 | 20190131 | 2 |
| 6 | 20190131 | 2 |

I want to get the following dataframe:

| index | period | category | category_count | period_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20181231 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 20181231 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 20181231 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 20190131 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 20190131 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

I tried to use various group by and aggregate logic but I always end up that period_count equals to category_count since the group by and aggregate will only aggregate through both groups (which are period and category in that case).

Is there a way to do a "nested" group by where one aggregation is done through both groups and the other is done through the first one?

Answer (score 0):

One can create both `category_count` and `period_count` with [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) as follows

```
df['category_count'] = df.groupby(['period', 'category'])['category'].transform('count')
df['period_count'] = df.groupby(['period'])['category'].transform('count')

[Out]:

         period  category  category_count  period_count
index                                                  
1      20181231         1               1             3
2      20181231         2               1             3
3      20181231         3               1             3
4      20190131         1               1             3
5      20190131         2               2             3
6      20190131         2               2             3
```